# I know what a javascript Promise is, but is there a name for "a function that returns a Promise"?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm writing a function that returns "a function that returns a promise," and I'm struggling to name and document my function.

Is there a name for "a function that returns a Promise"?

Note: "No" is an acceptable answer.

Comment: A function that returns a promise. Or a promisified function. Name it what it does; the promise is an implementation detail.

Comment: Good thing that no is an acceptable answer, because it's the correct one. Documentation of the function should simply include `@return Promise`

Comment: @svarog "promiseFactory()" suggests (at least in my head) that the function returns promises that are somewhat empty or waiting to be filled with something, i.e. not tied to any logic yet. In that sense, I think that not all functions that return promises are promise factories, in the same way that `Employee.getSalary()` is not a "decimalNumberFactory"

Comment: well, you're right, that's one option. i also like to use "promiseMe..." as a prefix. such as `promiseMeTimeout(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, no. There is not a canonical name for a function that returns a Promise. You can call it whatever you like so long as it is true to the idea that a Promise *captures* some asynchronous functionality. For example, *"an asynchronous function"*.

However, I would suggest simply using *"function that returns a Promise"*. This is most accurate when you consider that the function itself is not any different for its return value (as @DaveNewton said, the fact it returns a Promise is an *implementation detail*).

Comment: I personally think that *asynchronous function* is the best name for that.

Answer (score 1):

None that I know of.

There may be a more appropriate name, but even in that case, if I don't know it and you don't know it, there's a good chance that the person reading your documentation won't know it either. In other words, whatever name that is it is probably not well known, so using it in your documentation will not be of much help.

On the other hand, "function that returns a promise" will be easily understood by everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I am betting that after the [async functions](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/) proposal lands, people will start saying "async function" for this purpose.

In one sense that won't be strictly correct, since there can be promise-returning functions that are written without `async function` syntax. However, all functions written with `async function` syntax will be promise-returning.

On the other hand it's pretty correct anyway, since in modern JavaScript code, all functions that do something asynchronous should be returning promises, and all promise-returning functions should be doing something asynchronous.

So I'd probably use "async function".